# vlookup not working in vba but works in excel

Tags: vba

I have some data in a range in Cells A2:B11. What I'm trying to do is do a vlookup to return a value based on an input, put through the inputbox. However the Excel VBA Editor does not like the line of my code with the actual VLOOKUP function, but to me there is nothing wrong with it. Please can anyone help and tell me where I am going wrong. Here is the code.....

```
Sub getprice()

Dim PartNum As Variant
Dim Price As Double

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set pricelist = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B11")
PartNum= InputBox("provide the part number")

Price = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(partnum, pricelist, 2, false)
MsgBox partnum & "costs" & price

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works for me.  I suspect the problem is in the specific data you are using - what would a sample `PartNum` look like?  (E.g. is it something like `ABC-123-AS` or is it just `1234`?)

Comment: InputBox is going to return a string and if partNum is a number in the pricelist, it will not find a match.  You will need to change it to numbers.

Comment: what does  _VBA Editor does not like the line_  mean?

Comment: fyi: there is absolutely no reason to have this line in the code  `Sheets("Sheet1").Activate`

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced your `InputBox` with `Application.InputBox`, which let's you control what types of data the user can enter, to read more about it, go to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-inputbox-method-excel) .

Also, I've added an error traping criteria, in case `Vlookup` is unable to find a mtach for `PartNum` in `PriceList` range.

Other explanation inside the code below as comments.

***Code***

```
Sub getprice()

Dim PartNum As Long
Dim Price As Double
Dim PriceList As Range

' set the Range object directly, there's no need to select the worksheet first
Set PriceList = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B11")

' use Application.InputBox with Type 1, ensures only numeric values are entered
PartNum = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="provide the part number", Type:=1)
' if the user pressed Cancel
If Len(PartNum) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Part Number entere", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

' you need to trap a possible error in case Vlookup is unable to find a match in PriceList Range
If Not IsError(Application.VLookup(PartNum, PriceList, 2, False)) Then
    PartNum = Application.VLookup(PartNum, PriceList, 2, False)
    MsgBox PartNum & " costs " & Price
Else
    MsgBox PartNum & " not found in Range " & PriceList.Address
End If

End Sub
```